# Carregar página só quando imagem tal for carregada

Tags: jquery

Carregar página só quando imagem tal for carregada, como faço isso utilizando `JQuery`?

Tentei algumas coisas mas sem sucesso até agora, alguém me ajuda...

eu não tenho o id da imagem só o da div q ela tá dentro...

EDIT: Eu to usando um plugin jquery para imagem de fundo, o backstrech e essa imagem de fundo tem 2mb e demora pra carregar, o código que eu uso é esse:

```
<script src="jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.backstretch("fundo.gif");
</script>
```

o backstretch usa a div com class backstretch

tentei dai várias formas de fazer isso
tipo:

```
<script>
$(".backstretch").load(function() {
    $("#corpo").show();
});
</script>
```

e isso:

```
<script>
$("img.backstretch").load(function() {
    $("#corpo").show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: informe mais um menos como que é o trecho do seu html aqui para ficar mais fácil lhe ajudarmos

Comment: coloquei mais informações Rogerio, espero que ajude...

Comment: Faz o seguinte, verifique se não tem nenhum erro acontecendo no seu javascript que esteja interrompendo a execução do mesmo. Depois coloque um `alert` dentro das funções load e veja se elas estao sendo chamadas. De quebra por fim faça um teste e chame pela função `$('#corpo').show();` e veja se o resultado é o esperado.

Comment: na verdade não é erro no script, simplesmente ele funciona mas a imagem carrega depois de qualquer maneira...

Comment: Seguinte, coloque no seu CSS, informando que a imagem e o #corpo começam invisiveis (display:none / visibility:hidden). Coloque um HTML resumido da pagina pra eu entender melhor :).

Comment: Lembrando que o `show` só vai fazer efeito se seu elemento `#corpo` estiver com `display: none`. Se estiver com `visibility: hidden` - o que significa que ele está invisível, mas ainda ocupa espaço na página - o `show` não o afeta, seria necessário usar `.css("visibility", "visible")` nesse caso.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o evento LOAD da imagem em questao

```
$('#IDdaImagem').on('load',function(){ 
    //'Código para carregar a página/conteúdo' 
})
```

Img dentro de uma DIV

```
$('#IDdaDIV img').on('load',function(){ 
    //'Código para carregar a página/conteúdo' 
})
```

Comment: eu não tenho o id da imagem só o da div q ela tá dentro...

Comment: @user3230262 sem problema, voce pode informar pelo elemento imagem dentro da div X.

Answer (score 0):

Eu aconselho você usar dessa forma:

```
<script src="http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('body').css('display','block');
    });
</script>
```

De display none no body, quando a  pagina for 100% carregada o script faz com que ela apareça, você pode usar aqueles gifs de loading etc.

Comment: mas a página carrega e a imagem não

Comment: a imagem que eu preciso tem 2mb e nunca dá certo esse esquema do preloading

Comment: hmm, ja tentou usar bibliotecas de resize?
pode te ajudar de alguma maneira, se não sua pagina vai demorar a ser carregada pelo visto

Comment: é um gif animado de 2mb, quais bibliotecas de resize ?

Comment: O google tem uma, da uma pesquisada, eu desenvolvo em magento to por fora das bibliotecas, o proprio magento ja tem a dele, ele pega uma imagem pesada e redmensiona para o tamanho que eu quero, gerando uma nova imagem em cache tornando bem mais rapido o carregamento da imagem

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
    var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];        
    if (!img.complete) {
           img.src = "../imagens/sem_imagem.jpg" ;
     }
```

EDIT: obviamente não usei jquery, até porque é muito mais fácil