# jQuery - como medir o tempo de load de uma imagem em background

Tags: jquery, css

Como correr código quando uma imagem usada como `background` está carregada?

Tentei :

```
$ ('#IDdaImagem').on('load', function () {
     / / 'Código parágrafo CARREGAR uma page / Conteúdo' 
})
```

e não funciona a imagem continua sendo carregada depois...

**é uma imagem de fundo**, e uso um plugin jQuery para abrir em outras resoluções, o backstretch, ele usa uma div com classe backstretch, como eu carrego esta imagem Fundo com 2mb antes de o conteúdo do site?

eu testei isso e funciona, mas não no elemento que eu vou dar show, só no alert.

```
<script>
$('.backstretch img').load(function() {
    alert('done loading image');
    $("#corpo").show();
});
</script>
```

---

Isto não funciona:

```
<script>
$ ('#IDdaImagem').on('load', function () { // no space
      $("#corpo").show();
}) 
</script>
```

Isto funciona:

```
<script>
$ ('#IDdaImagem').on('load', function () { // no space
      alert ('Test');
}) 
</script>
```

Comment: Como está o elemento `#corpo` antes do script executar? Se seu estilo estiver como `display: none` deve funcionar; se estiver como `visibility: hidden`, não (pois são coisas distintas).

Comment: Outra coisa: vi sua pergunta ["Carregar página só quando imagem tal for carregada"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12005/carregar-pagina-so-quando-imagem-tal-for-carregada), não sei se esta pode ser considerada duplicata dela ou não. Vou deixar pra comunidade decidir...

Answer (score 1):

Não creio que seja possível medir o `load` de um background. Uma ideia que pode testar é carregar a imagem para uma `<img>` que nunca vai ser usada no DOM. Será usada como "teste" para saber quando a imagem está carregada na cache do computador e aí disponível para ser usada como `background`.

Fiz este código:

```
var scriptLido = new Date().getTime();
var imagemFalsa = $('<img />');

imagemFalsa.on('load', function () {
    var imagemCarregada = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(imagemCarregada - scriptLido, 'Imagem carregada');
});

imagemFalsa.attr("src", "http://scienceblogs.com/startswithabang/files/2013/05/chemical_composition_universe.jpeg");


$('#imagemEscondida').ready(function () {
    var domReady = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(domReady - scriptLido, 'domReady');
});
```

E deu-me este resultado:

> **2**   "domReady"
>   **330** "Imagem carregada"

Isto quer dizer que a imagem estava carregada 328 milisegundos depois do evento DOMReady, que por sua vez estava 2 ms desfazada em relação ao inicio do código. Numa página a sério estes numeros serão talvez maiores visto o meu script ser bem pequeno.

Curiosamente, e como confirmação, quando carreguei a página de novo, já com a imagem em cache, o `load` ("Imagem carregada" ) veio somente 6 ms depois.

Por isso acho que pode usar este truque.

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/K2p6N/)